# Restoring emacs default settings

Tags: emacs

Very new to emacs, I've only been using it for about two days and haven't (intentionally) changed much of it. However I noticed today that I can no longer add and delete characters the way I was when I first started using it. For example when the cursor is on the "r" in :

"Hello Wrld"
when I try to add an "o", it used to look like:
"Hello World" but now it looks like "Hello Wold"

Similarly, when I try to delete an "o" in
"hello woorld"
it appears as "hello wo rld" instead of the correct "hello world"

Thanks,
Jimmy

**Problem solved, I was in overwrite-mode. Thanks everybody**

Comment: Don't be shy -- open up your `.emacs` file and take a peek.  If you stick with Emacs, eventually you will be modifying that by hand once you understand what's going on.

Comment: I have, but I don't know what I'm looking for for this specific issue.

Comment: It can't be very big (after only two days) -- you could probably even paste it into your question and then you'd have a definitive answer.

Comment: I suggest run `C-h c` and then press the key(s) you normally use to delete characters. You'll see the name of the command used. Also from your question it seems you set your *computer*'s insert to "off". If you press the touch `insert` it might go back.

Comment: Is this affecting 1 buffer that you put in Overwrite mode, or all buffers?

Comment: Nothing in your `.emacs` file appears to be the cause of your issue.  You really only have default color settings and that's it.  Perhaps there are some settings you can add that will give you the desired affect.

Comment: This link may be helpful -- it discusses `overwrite-mode`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq.html#Overwrite-mode

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't realize i had overwrite-mode enabled.

Comment: @jimmmy Now that your problem is solved, you should answer your question and accept it, in order to close that question

Answer (score 0):

As lawlist and you commented, you had overwrite-mode enabled.  You can enable and disable it with

```
M-x overwrite-mode
```

or check your init (.emacs) file to see if for some reason there's a line like this

```
(overwrite-mode t)
```

in which case you'd have to delete it.